# Ember js, in heroku production, live reload fails to load and time out and loading spinner keeps spinning

Tags: javascript, ember.js, livereload

I just deployed a simple side project using ember and rails.
Evenything is good but when first enter the webpage, the browser loading spinner keeps spinning.

I checked on the console and it has an error saying fetching ember cli live reload has timed out.

This does not happen on local and live reload works fine on local.
How can I fix this?

Thanks!

[spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwHc7.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvON3.png)

Comment: I'm assuming that Ember's "live reload" is similar to React's "hot reload" but that's only to be used during development so that the app is immediately rebuilt when changes are made. Why do you have it running when you deploy it?

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy your app to production or herokup (or anywhere), you'll want to build it in production mode.

So, for ember, that'd be:

```bash
ember build --environment=production
```

This will make the app more performant and get rid of any development code, such as live-reload.